# Error while upgrading from Fedora 35 to Fedora 36: VirtualBox requires libvpx.so.6()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed

Tags: fedora, upgrade, dist-upgrade

While upgrading my system from Fedora 35 to Fedora 36,
I first ran

```bsh
sudo dnf upgrade --refresh
```

And then,

```bsh
sudo dnf system-upgrade download --releasever=36
```

But it is giving rise to this error:

```bsh
Before you continue ensure that your system is fully upgraded by running "dnf --refresh upgrade". Do you want to continue [y/N]: y
Copr repo for spotify-tui owned by atim         1.7 kB/s | 3.3 kB     00:01    
Copr repo for PyCharm owned by phracek          2.5 kB/s | 3.6 kB     00:01    
created by dnf config-manager from https://brav  21 kB/s | 3.3 kB     00:00    
created by dnf config-manager from https://brav 120 kB/s | 9.2 kB     00:00    
Docker CE Stable - x86_64                        22 kB/s | 3.5 kB     00:00    
determining the fastest mirror (10 hosts).. done.--  B/s |   0  B     --:-- ETA
Fedora 36 - x86_64                              2.0 kB/s | 5.6 kB     00:02    
Fedora 36 openh264 (From Cisco) - x86_64        1.1 kB/s | 989  B     00:00    
Fedora Modular 36 - x86_64                      7.8 kB/s | 5.5 kB     00:00    
Fedora 36 - x86_64 - Updates                    7.5 kB/s | 5.5 kB     00:00    
Fedora 36 - x86_64 - Updates                    1.2 MB/s | 4.0 MB     00:03    
Fedora Modular 36 - x86_64 - Updates            4.2 kB/s | 5.4 kB     00:01    
packages for the GitHub CLI                     9.6 kB/s | 3.0 kB     00:00    
google-chrome                                   4.9 kB/s | 1.3 kB     00:00    
google-chrome                                   6.8 kB/s | 3.6 kB     00:00    
MEGAsync                                        1.1 kB/s | 1.5 kB     00:01    
pgadmin4                                         82  B/s | 146  B     00:01    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'pgAdmin4':
  - Status code: 404 for https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/yum/fedora/fedora-36-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 87.238.57.227)
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'pgAdmin4': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
PostgreSQL common RPMs for Fedora 36 - x86_64   115  B/s | 195  B     00:01    
PostgreSQL common RPMs for Fedora 36 - x86_64    76 kB/s | 231 kB     00:03    
PostgreSQL 14 for Fedora 36 - x86_64             83  B/s | 195  B     00:02    
PostgreSQL 14 for Fedora 36 - x86_64             49 kB/s | 177 kB     00:03    
PostgreSQL 13 for Fedora 36 - x86_64             99  B/s | 195  B     00:01    
PostgreSQL 13 for Fedora 36 - x86_64             46 kB/s | 175 kB     00:03    
PostgreSQL 12 for Fedora 36 - x86_64            105  B/s | 195  B     00:01    
PostgreSQL 12 for Fedora 36 - x86_64             66 kB/s | 168 kB     00:02    
PostgreSQL 11 for Fedora 36 - x86_64             94  B/s | 195  B     00:02    
PostgreSQL 11 for Fedora 36 - x86_64             37 kB/s | 165 kB     00:04    
PostgreSQL 10 for Fedora 36 - x86_64             93  B/s | 195  B     00:02    
PostgreSQL 10 for Fedora 36 - x86_64             37 kB/s | 128 kB     00:03    
RPM Fusion for Fedora 36 - Free                 1.9 kB/s | 2.2 kB     00:01    
RPM Fusion for Fedora 36 - Free - Updates        11 kB/s |  10 kB     00:00    
RPM Fusion for Fedora 36 - Free - Updates        41 kB/s |  75 kB     00:01    
RPM Fusion for Fedora 36 - Nonfree - NVIDIA Dri  14 kB/s | 9.8 kB     00:00    
RPM Fusion for Fedora 36 - Nonfree - Steam       19 kB/s | 9.4 kB     00:00    
Sublime Text - x86_64 - Stable                  3.0 kB/s | 2.9 kB     00:00    
Visual Studio Code                              8.6 kB/s | 3.0 kB     00:00    
Visual Studio Code                              7.3 MB/s |  25 MB     00:03    
Ignoring repositories: pgAdmin4
no group 'arm-tools' from environment 'workstation-product-environment'
No match for group package "qgnomeplatform"
No match for group package "reiserfs-utils"
No match for group package "xorg-x11-drv-armsoc"
No match for group package "intel-media-driver"
No match for group package "authselect-compat"
No match for group package "google-noto-sans-syriac-estrangela-fonts"
No match for group package "google-noto-sans-syriac-eastern-fonts"
No match for group package "ubuntu-title-fonts"
No match for group package "khmer-os-fasthad-fonts"
No match for group package "libguestfs-tools"
No match for group package "mpir-devel"
No match for group package "bcm283x-firmware"
No match for group package "kanjistrokeorders-fonts"
No match for group package "polarsys-b612-sans-fonts"
No match for group package "yanone-tagesschrift-fonts"
No match for group package "google-noto-sans-tibetan-fonts"
No match for group package "cvsgraph"
No match for group package "drehatlas-xaporho-fonts"
No match for group package "google-noto-sans-syriac-western-fonts"
No match for group package "libusbx-devel"
No match for group package "culmus-shofar-fonts"
No match for group package "tlomt-junction-fonts"
No match for group package "vollkorn-fonts"
No match for group package "drehatlas-warender-bibliothek-fonts"
Error: 
 Problem: package VirtualBox-6.1-6.1.30_148432_fedora33-1.x86_64 requires libvpx.so.6()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
  - libvpx-1.10.0-2.fc35.x86_64 does not belong to a distupgrade repository
  - problem with installed package VirtualBox-6.1-6.1.30_148432_fedora33-1.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)
```

Adding `--skip-broken` doesn't seem to solve the problem. I get the same error. Tried running `sudo dnf remove libvpx-1.10.0-2.fc35.x86_64`.
But this gives another warning:

```bsh
Error: 
 Problem: The operation would result in removing the following protected packages: gnome-shell
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)
```

How can I upgrade my Fedora distro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall the package, do the upgrade, then reinstall:

1. `sudo rpm -e VirtualBox-6.1`
2. Upgrade.
3. Install VirtualBox from [here](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.34/VirtualBox-6.1-6.1.34_150636_fedora36-2.x86_64.rpm) or better yet install their [repo](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/rpm/fedora/virtualbox.repo) to `/etc/yum.repos.d/` and then `sudo dnf install VirtualBox-6.1`.

Comment: The package doesn't install after upgrade to Fedora 36 and gives this error: `nothing provides libvpx.so.6()(64bit) needed by VirtualBox-6.1-6.1.20_143896_fedora33-1.x86_64` despite that the libvpx package is installed.

Comment: For some reasons you continue to install the **fedora33** version.

Comment: If you've already upgraded to kernel 5.18, you need to install a test build e.g. from here https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/ as VirtualBox 6.1.34 is not compatible with this kernel.